# Posicionar controles com bootstrap não alinhando

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso fazer o seguinte: Label em cima e controle em baixo dos labels. Peguei o exemplo da própria página do `twitter bootstrap` e não está dando certo. Abaixo o meu código:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <form role="form"><!--A tag ul contem os titulos das abas-->

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="txtCnpjPdv" >CNPJ/Razão Social:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control;col-sm-2" id="txtCnpjPdv" placeholder="Digite o Cnpj">
            @*</div>

            <div class="form-group">*@
              <label for="txtContato" >Contato:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control;col-sm-2" id="txtContato" placeholder="Digite o Cnpj">
            @*</div>*@

            <label for="ddlFiltrarRede" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Filtrar Rede:</label>
            @*<div class="col-sm-3">*@
              <select class="form-control;col-sm-2" name="ddlTipoEvento" id="ddlFiltrarRede" >
                <option value="SemFiltro">Sem Filtro</option>
                <option value="Associativa">Associativa</option>
                <option value="Franquia">Franquia</option>
                <option value="Propria">Própria</option>
              </select>
            @*</div>*@

            <label for="ddlFiltrarStatus" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Filtrar Status:</label>
            @*<div class="col-sm-3">*@
              <select class="form-control;col-sm-2" name="ddlTipoEvento" id="ddlFiltrarStatus" >
                <option value="SemFiltro">Sem Filtro</option>
                <option value="Ok">Ok</option>
                <option value="Atençao">Atenção</option>
                <option value="Erro">Erro</option>
                <option value="NaoCadastrado">Não Cadastrado</option>
                <option value="Desativado">Desativado</option>
              </select>
            @*</div>*@

            <label for="ddlFiltrarVisao" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Visão:</label>
            @*<div class="col-sm-3">*@
              <select class="form-control;col-sm-2" name="ddlTipoEvento" id="ddlFiltrarVisao" >
                <option value="Geral">Geral</option>
                <option value="SouzaCruz">Souza Cruz</option>
              </select>
            @*</div>*@
        </div>
       </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Se eu retirar essa parte dos controles select(`class="col-sm-2 control-label"`), fica tudo na mesma linha. O que quero é label em cima e controle em baixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema parece ser no atributo `class` de seu `input`, onde

`class="form-control;col-sm-2"`

Altere para

`class="form-control col-sm-2"`

```
   <form role="form"><!--A tag ul contem os titulos das abas-->

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="txtCnpjPdv" >CNPJ/Razão Social:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-2" id="txtCnpjPdv" placeholder="Digite o Cnpj" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="txtContato" >Contato:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-2" id="txtContato" placeholder="Digite o Cnpj" />
            </div>

            <label for="ddlFiltrarRede" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Filtrar Rede:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <select class="form-control col-sm-2" name="ddlTipoEvento" id="ddlFiltrarRede" >
                <option value="SemFiltro">Sem Filtro</option>
                <option value="Associativa">Associativa</option>
                <option value="Franquia">Franquia</option>
                <option value="Propria">Própria</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <label for="ddlFiltrarStatus" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Filtrar Status:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <select class="form-control col-sm-2" name="ddlTipoEvento" id="ddlFiltrarStatus" >
                <option value="SemFiltro">Sem Filtro</option>
                <option value="Ok">Ok</option>
                <option value="Atençao">Atenção</option>
                <option value="Erro">Erro</option>
                <option value="NaoCadastrado">Não Cadastrado</option>
                <option value="Desativado">Desativado</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <label for="ddlFiltrarVisao" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Visão:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-3">
              <select class="form-control col-sm-2" name="ddlTipoEvento" id="ddlFiltrarVisao" >
                <option value="Geral">Geral</option>
                <option value="SouzaCruz">Souza Cruz</option>
              </select>
           </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

**Exemplo:** **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9vT5/)**

#### EDITADO

Para posicionar os labels em uma linha e os controles em outra, você precisa usar uma `div` com classe `row` para cada, exemplo:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
         <label for="txtCnpjPdv" >CNPJ/Razão Social:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
       <label for="txtContato" >Contato:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <label for="ddlFiltrarRede" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Filtrar Rede:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <label for="ddlFiltrarStatus" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Filtrar Status:</label>
    </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <label for="ddlFiltrarVisao" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Visão:</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-2" id="txtCnpjPdv" placeholder="Digite o Cnpj" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
       <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-2" id="txtContato" placeholder="Digite o Cnpj" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <select class="form-control col-sm-2" name="ddlTipoEvento" id="ddlFiltrarRede" >
                <option value="SemFiltro">Sem Filtro</option>
                <option value="Associativa">Associativa</option>
                <option value="Franquia">Franquia</option>
                <option value="Propria">Própria</option>
              </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
         <select class="form-control col-sm-2" name="ddlTipoEvento" id="ddlFiltrarStatus" >
                <option value="SemFiltro">Sem Filtro</option>
                <option value="Ok">Ok</option>
                <option value="Atençao">Atenção</option>
                <option value="Erro">Erro</option>
                <option value="NaoCadastrado">Não Cadastrado</option>
                <option value="Desativado">Desativado</option>
              </select>
    </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <select class="form-control col-sm-2" name="ddlTipoEvento" id="ddlFiltrarVisao" >
                <option value="Geral">Geral</option>
                <option value="SouzaCruz">Souza Cruz</option>
              </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Exemplo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9vT5/1/)**

Comment: Não deu certo, pois os controles ficaram com width=100% e isso não dá certo. Há como eu diminuir o tamanho? A única forma, foi da forma que eu havia feito. Todos os labels devem estar na mesma linha e todos os controles ficam na mesma linha abaixo dos labels.

Comment: @pnet dessa forma que esta querendo ? http://jsfiddle.net/R9vT5/1/

Comment: Eu preciso alinhar os labels em uma mesma linha e também os controles, em baixo dos labels, correspondendo a cada label, óbvio. Essa é a minha necessidade. Estou tendo muita dificuldade em trabalhar com bootstrap, em coisas simples, como essa.

Comment: @pnet mais é isso, da forma que enviei, se não for, coloque uma imagem para exemplificar, fica mais fácil de entender.

Comment: @pnet você pode aumentar uma coluna ao invés de `col-xs-2 col...2` coloque `col-xs-3 col...3`, a soma de todas as colunas tem que ser 12, veja se isso resolve

Comment: Não deu certo. Se eu colocar Filtra/Status, aí dá certo, porque ele considera uma palavra apenas. Quando há duas é que ele quebra.

Comment: @pnet no CSS coloque `label {white-space:nowrap;}`

Comment: Agora sim, o post está fechado. Muito obrigado @abfurlan. Funcionou sim, dessa forma.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é tirar o controle de grid do elemento HTML input e colocar em uma estrutura div e sempre a div com o controle de coluna deve estar dentro de uma div class="row":

CNPJ/Razão Social:
               
        
    
    
        ...Outros controles para completar o GRID 12colunas

Espero ter ajudado meu amigo!!

Comment: Por favor inclua algum código fonte para auxiliar na solução do problema, dê uma olhada no nosso [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para verificar como melhorar as suas respostas e evitar que elas sejam fechadas por estarem incompletas.